# Codeigniter URL redirection and routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, url-routing

I am trying to redirect URL's with Codeighiter routing. I could not write routing for the following.

If the URL comes with `/api/some/some` I want to redirect it to `api/some/some`, otherwise I want to redirect the URL to `/home/index`.

i.e if any URL starts with `api/` i don't want to change that URL other wise i want to redirect it to default controller `home/index`

What i tried is mapping the codeigniter URL routing.

```
$route['api/(:any)'] = 'api/(:any)';

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/';
```

I am trying with codeigniter URL routing technique but i am not able to achieve this.

Is this is the way to redirect URL's at codeigniter level with out touching server side redirection or is there any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1. Using CodeIgniter routing**

try this in your `application/config/routes.php`

```
$route ['api/(:any)'] = "api/$1";
$route ['(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";
$route ['default_controller'] = "home";
```

1. For any matching `()` in patter, you'l need to add respective `$1` or `$2`, `$3`.. based on position of that `()` patter. i.e for first `()` its $1, for second `()` its `$2` and so on.
2. You'l need to set your default controller to `home`.

**Solution 2. Using .htaccess page redirection**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api(.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/index$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /home/index [R=301,QSA,L]
```