# Proper way to redirect mysite.com/{id} ignoring controllers in CI3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

Im looking for a way to redirect mysite.com/{id} to a, for example, a user's profile. (Similar the way Facebook does).

Codeigniter has some URI rules like "mysite.com/{controller}/{parameters}".

Is there a way to detect when a string is a **controller** and when is a **username**?

For example:

https://www.facebook.com/zuck <- This is **Mark**!

https://www.facebook.com/help <- This is **not** a user!

Thank you!

Comment: this is a duplicate post [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197088/codeigniter-url-redirection-and-routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your routes in order

first, your static page

next, your dynamic page